# Vue.js state is not updating: Resolved

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

> Resolved

I have a component that loads a list of service from backend and want to list them in a table. It is loading the data from API but not showing in the table. I am using it with Laravel.

VueJS Component `ResourceTable.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <a class="button" v-on:click.native.prevent="services">Load</a>
    <b-table :data="items" :columns="columns"></b-table>
    {{items}}
    <br>
    {{ done }}
  </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name: 'resource-table',
        props: ['resource'],
        data() {
            return {
                loading: false,
                done: 'loading',
                items: [],
                columns: [{
                    field: 'name',
                    label: 'Name'
                }],
                host: 'http://services.local/api/v1'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            /*
             * Load async data
             */
            services: function() {
                console.log('loading data');
            this.loading = false;
            // const vm = this;
            axios.get(`${this.host}/${this.resource}`)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                this.items = data.data;
                console.log(this.items)
                this.loading = false;
                this.done = 'loaded';
                this.$toast.open('Data load complete')
                })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.services()
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<resource-table resource="workspaces"></resource-table>
```

The API is working and I am getting the data from server but it is not updating in the table.

If I predefine some values in `items` array, it lists that data but it is not showing the data from API.

> **Resolved**
>
> I had JS file included twice. After removing one from the bottom, it worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are you sure `data.data` is what you want it to be? Would be worth logging its value to double check.

Comment: @JamesCoyle `console.log(this.items)` prints the array.

Comment: Are the other values updating correctly? Does it work if you replace `services: function()` with `services()`?

Comment: You deconstruct your `data` object `({ data })` but you are appending `this.items = data.data`. Try `this.items = data`

Comment: @RuChernChong that was my thought but OP says that `this.items` contains the array.

Comment: @JamesCoyle "it lists that data but it is not showing the data from API." It seemed like the pre-defined data is showing but not the data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel, but I think this is the problematic part:

```
this.items = data.data;
```

You need to place your data into *items* with a loop. Otherwise, the data in items is not reactive.

Like this (running a for loop, you also iterate with forEach):

```
this.items.splice(0); // just in case you want to replace already existing data

for (let i = 0, l = data.data.length; i < l; i++) {
  this.items.push(data.data[i]);
}
```

I haven't checked the code, but I think you get the idea;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use created() lifecycle hook instead of mounted()

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks